# Mesos & Hadoop: How to get the running job input data size?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mesos

I'm running Hadoop 1.2.1 on top of Mesos 0.14. My goal is to log the input data size, running time, cpu usage, memory usage, and so on for optimization purposes later. All of these but data size are obtained using Sigar.

Is there any way I can get the input data size of **any** job which is running?

For example, when I'm running hadoop example's [terasort](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/package-summary.html), I need to get the teragen's generated data size before the job actually runs. If I'm running [Wordcount example](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount), I need to get the wordcount input file size. I need to get the data size automatically since I won't be able to know what job will be run inside this framework later.

I'm using Java to write some of the mesos library code. Preferably, I want to get the data size inside MesosExecutor class. For some reason, upgrading Hadoop/Mesos isn't an option.

Any suggestions or related API will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I found some hint [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.0/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobInProgress.java): `inputLength` and `getInputLength()`, but those two are `private`.

Answer (score 0):

Does `hadoop fs -dus` satisfy your requirement? Before submit the job to hadoop, calculate the input file size and pass it as params to your executor.